# Setup Flash seeking / streaming with mediaelement.js (apache+php)?

Tags: mediaelement.js, pseudo-streaming

Can users with *older browsers* or *video formats* which require *Flash fallback* jump to certain time in video if it isn't already buffered?

Does **flashmediaelement.swf** support seeking using byte-range / pseudostreaming at all?

Firebug (Net tab) doesn't show correct headers needed for such streaming (206 Partial Content).
- request : Range
- response : Content-Range

Those headers appear only when native player is active.

**Articles with possible solutions:**

- [Apache FLV streaming done right!](http://tperspective.blogspot.com/2009/02/apache-flv-streaming-done-right.html)
- [Streaming FLV on Apache / Ubuntu](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fbarrasbin.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F05%2F08%2Fstreaming-de-flv-no-apacheubuntu%2F)

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717430/seeking-videos-beyond-the-buffer-line-in-flash-mode/15833547#15833547