# Seeking videos beyond the buffer line in Flash-mode

Tags: mediaelement.js, pseudo-streaming

The webserver-modules `ngx_http_mp4_module` or `mod_h264_streaming` allow Flash-clients to seek a video beyond the downloaded buffer line, using a "start"-parameter, e.g.:

```
http://server.com/path/to/video.mp4?start=10
```

Is there a chance to enable this feature in mediaelement.js?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, pseudostreaming in Mediaelement flash player is not implemented.

Look at this thread: [http streamed MP4 vidéo is not randomly seekable in flash](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/280). But someone is working on it;  hopefully, we'll get the feature in the future :)

**Edit :**

They're now working on it (see [this news](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/pull/814)). It only works with mp4 files at the moment. You have to set `enablePseudoStreaming` to `true` to enable the feature.

Sample code:

```
var Player = new MediaElement('video_player', {
    features: [ 'flash' ],
    enablePseudoStreaming: true
});
```

The player will then make request such as this one:

```
http://example.com/video.mp4?start=40
```

The start query parameter specify the second in which you want to start pseudostream. You could also set another one with the option `pseudoStreamingStartQueryParam`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is there any additional setting I need to do?

Comment: Is your web server enabled for pseudostreaming of videos? (features like the ones stated in the question).

Comment: Not sure. Using heroku now, I guess I have to use one of the two modules mentioned in the question?

Comment: I am not sure, how to go about this. Any direction would be great.

Comment: Yes, that feature is required to make everything work. I had to install `mod_h264_streaming` in my Apache for this. I don't know what to do on Heroku though :P

Comment: Have a look: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash/ . You could also try to throw a JWplayer page with the url of your video. If it doesn’t work, you'll have to do something to your heroku instance.